# Automation of ssreflect, Coq while dealing with contradicted hypotheses about nat numbers

Tags: coq, ssreflect

While using `ssreflect` in the following lemma:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool ssrnat eqtype.

Lemma nat_dec n m: (m <= n) -> (~~ (m <= n)) -> False.
Proof.
  intros A notA.
  (* auto. *)
  red in A.
  red in notA.
  (* auto. *)
  rewrite -> A in notA.
  auto.
Qed.
```

May I ask why those `autos`, that I commented out, do not work at those proof states? as it seems to me that these states already observe contradiction in the context.

And is there some automation by `ssreflect` to prove this lemma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you remove some notations and the coercions you get a clearer view of what is going on in this goal:

```
Lemma nat_dec n m: (m <= n = true) -> (negb (m <= n) = true) -> False.
```

In particular, `auto` doesn't work as it is not powerful enough to reason about the behavior of `negb`. However, when you rewrite, your goal becomes:

```
Lemma nat_dec n m: (m <= n = true) -> (negb true = true) -> False.
```

so after simplification, `false = true` is in the context and `auto` can indeed close the goal.